# any best practices for storing and accessing oAuth access_token?

Tags: security, optimization, database-design, oauth-2.0

Considering the user has helped me to generate an access token and other stuff(refresh token/instance-url) in my application.Every time I do a job for the user I have to use this token and communicate with his application.
What are the best practices to store these access token with userId information?
Also any best practices to minimize the db calls for each request to the user's application?
The questions asks at the database design level inputs.

Answer (score 1):

If you are mostly focusing on modern browser versions, you could use HTML5 session storage (i.e. sessionStorage) to store your access token. Session storage is better than local storage (i.e. localStorage) from a security standpoint. See more information here:

[OWASP HTML5 Security Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HTML5_Security_Cheat_Sheet)

and here:

[Introduction to sessionStorage](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/07/21/introduction-to-sessionstorage/)

Be aware, though, of some of the limitations per browser version regarding how well session storage is cleared or deleted when you keep the tab or window open.

As far as minimizing calls to the database, you have to weigh how much you want to store on the client side (size) versus staleness of data (cache) versus the likelihood of keeping sensitive data on the client too long (security). You may also look at HTML5 local storage or client-side databases

@RobertHurlbut

Comment: Thanks for you comment @Robert but what I was looking is at the database design level.Maybe I would update my question